# Volley sending multiple requests tracking

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley

I  was going through volley library documentation with the following example

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
            mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

My question is if i add an other request(similar request i.e. StringRequest) request to the queue, how can i map my request to response since the response is asynchronous.

```
1request --> 1response.
2request --> 2response.
```

I don't have any priorities for request and should be done concurrently (not sequential requests).

Comment: You need to implement callbacks. When a request from the queue finishes, it will trigger the callback and you can map it, then the next, and the next and so on...

Comment: You can also add any "ID" in your request parameters and send the same `ID` in response as well to identify.

Comment: Moreover, you can also create the `CustomStringRequest` and pass the `Listener` to that request. `OnResponse` trigger that listener